# Jbuilder gem standalone not rendering anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, jbuilder

Jbuilder standalone will not render anything. Do I need a configuration parameter to get it to work in Rails 3.2.8?

```
1.9.2p320 :257 > Jbuilder
 => Jbuilder 
1.9.2p320 :258 > Jbuilder.new {|json| json.foo 'bar'}.target!
 => "{}"
```

Thanks a million.

UPDATE

The encode method works.

```
1.9.2p320 :016 > Jbuilder.encode {|json| json.foo 'bar'}
 => "{\"Foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

But I'd like to use nested Jbuilder objects to construct more complex JSON.  The documentation says I should be able to get back a builder object and call target! to get the json string. I'm really quite stumped.

Comment: Do you see any output, logs?

Comment: No, that's taken straight off if the rails console. When implemented in my models, it behaves the same. Just a blank JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I was using the documenation on the Github, but using the version of the gem on rubygems.org

replacing:

```
gem 'jbuilder'
```

with:

```
gem 'jbuilder', :git => "https://github.com/rails/jbuilder.git", :tag => "v0.9.1"
```

in my Gemfile solved the problem.